# S3Cmd Parameter Problem: Nothing to upload error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I am uploading a file from computer to s3 bucket, but the thing is upon using this command `s3cmd put c:/ok/ok.pdf s3://bucket_name/` i am getting an error

> PARAMETER PROBLEM: NOTHING TO UPLOAD

which has no solution i think, i am using the steps from the s3cmd manual.

Any one here to tell me, what is going on ?

Comment: Side-note: These days it is recommended to use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than s3cmd.

Comment: `s3cmd` has a lot nicer user interface than `awscli`, it handles wildcards more naturally, and offers resume stopped uploads. The weakness of `s3cmd` is that it isn't multi-threaded, so it's substantially slower than `awscli` for large files. `s4cmd` appears to be a more recently maintained fork of `s3cmd` that provides the usability benefits of `s3cmd` and matches the performance of `awscli`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably can't find the file on your local machine. Be sure the file exists and try use '\'

```
s3cmd put c:\ok\ok.pdf s3://bucket_name/
```